# How to delete several items in a list based on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have this `List` of these objects:

```
public class DutyAssignmentEntry
{
    private string _Date;
    private string _Week;
    private int _Template;
    private AssignmentMode _Mode;
    private List<Assignment> _Assignments;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Date
    {
        get => _Date; set => _Date = value;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Week
    {
        get => _Week; set => _Week = value;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Template
    {
        get => _Template; set => _Template = value;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public AssignmentMode Mode
    {
        get => _Mode; set => _Mode = value;
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<Assignment> Assignments
    {
        get => _Assignments; set => _Assignments = value;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Key
    {
        get => _Template + "_" + _Date;
    }

    public DutyAssignmentEntry()
    {
        _Date = "";
        _Week = "";
        _Template = 0;
        _Mode = AssignmentMode.Weekly;
        _Assignments = new List<Assignment>();
    }

    public DateTime ToDate()
    {
        int iYear = Convert.ToInt32(Date.Substring(1, 4));
        int iMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Date.Substring(5, 2));
        int iDate = Convert.ToInt32(Date.Substring(7, 2));

        return new DateTime(iYear, iMonth, iDate);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have implemented a `ToDate` public method. I want to create another method that is passed in two dates (no time stamp) and I want to remove from my list all items that are within or equal to the stated date range.

In addition, I have a `Template` property and this value must also match.

Now, I understand how to navigate the list and check each enty one by one by testing the `ToDate` value and the `Template` value. But can I do it more elegantly?

So I have:

```
_DutyAssignments = new List<DutyAssignmentEntry>();
```

A new method:

```
public void DeleteDutyHistoryAssignments(DateTime datStart, DateTime datEnd, long lTemplate)
{
    // Fancy way to remove all the items in the list where
    // item.ToDate() >= datStart.Date and
    // item.ToDate() <= datEnd.Date and
    // item.Template = lTemplate
}
```

Comment: Slightly OT, but `Date` should be `DateTime`, not `String`. It's not a great idea to repeatedly parse the string like that. Use a LINQ Where -- or multiple chained Wheres -- to filter the list. It's easy to google, there are a million examples. Or write a loop. Do you need help writing a loop, or do you need help comparing a date?

Comment: If you can already do it with iteration then what's wrong with that? LINQ will just do the same under the covers.

Comment: Note that when modifying a collection a `for` loop that iterates backwards is cleanest. You can't modify a collection when enumerating it with a `foreach` or with linq, although you could create a _new_ collection with either.

Comment: @EdPlunkett For reasons I have used `string` because the entry is formatted `WYYYYMMDD`. Thus I convert to a `DateTime` using my `ToDate` method. LINQ sounds the way to go.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That's not a good reason.

Comment: @EdPlunkett There is no need to discuss that. It is part oif a larger project which I have to fit in with. At this stage I am not looking  that the Date member being a `DateTime` or `string` but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Now that I have it working I will have a look at your suggestion. It occurs to me that I could create a public field that is not written to XML and that automatically set when the "Date" is set. This way it does the parse only once. Then I can adjust the filtering code to use the date variable. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Even better. I worked out how I could directly support the DateTime variable alone with the XML serialization etc. All good. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `List<T>` method [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
_DutyAssignment.RemoveAll(x =>
  x.ToDate() >= datStart.Date &&
  x.ToDate() <= datEnd.Date &&
  x.Template == lTemplate
);
```